# IE 7 Issue HTML / CSS

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

Hey ya'll I am having an issue with IE 7.... I have a header and some text, in firefox, ie 8, 9, chrome there is some space in between. however in IE 7 is non.

http://jamessuske.com/thornwood2/

HTML CODE

```
<div class="contentHeader">

 Thornwood Fine Homes

</div><!--contentHeader-->

<div class="contentTextIndex">

<p>In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Curabitur sed augue eget elit tristique venenatis. In ligula dui, facilisis in varius vitae, ullamcorper at risus. Mauris dictum aliquam massa, in elementum lacus vehicula quis. Aliquam erat volutpat. Aenean velit enim, rutrum ut laoreet ac, convallis eu orci. Etiam ac justo iaculis nunc iaculis mattis. Nam porta, lacus ac lobortis congue, leo nunc scelerisque leo, a sodales odio neque nec ligula. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Sed vel sem eu eros congue elementum in tincidunt neque. </p><p>Cras sed pretium quam. Morbi metus lorem, pulvinar a lacinia sed, molestie at ipsum. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Donec et justo metus, id vehicula erat. Nam ullamcorper mattis accumsan. Phasellus euismod egestas posuere. Nulla sed leo nulla. In sagittis interdum justo, ornare euismod ligula lacinia ac. Aliquam erat volutpat. </p>

</div><!--contentTextIndex-->
```

CSS CODE

```
.contentHeader{
font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
font-size:36px;
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
}

.contentTextIndex{
width:350px;
font-size:16px;
float:left;
}
```

Thanks for help :)

Comment: I'm getting big black chunks missing from your content body on Firefox 7.0.1

Answer (score 0):

This is because browsers have different default margins for various elements, just set them explicitly like this

```
.contentTextIndex{
width:350px;
font-size:16px;
float:left;
margin:10px 0px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks that did help...but now there is an issue with Firefox...http://jamessuske.com/thornwood2/

Comment: uhu, I answered ur original question tho so erm *cough cough*!

Comment: and yeah, I just checked in FF 7.0.1 and it worked absolutely fine for me!

Comment: well the correct thing to do would be accept the answer and then post a separate question for the other unrelated issue (not sure if it is an issue tho cuz as I say it tested fine)